# How to dynamically add buttons to HBox created in fxml?

Tags: java, javafx, hbox

I want to add buttons to created HBox, in fxml. Everything has been drawn, and I'm collecting some data from database, creating buttons, but when I try to add it tho said HBox, it won't add them.

```
FXMLLoader myLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml_cart.fxml"));
AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane) myLoader.load();
Scene scene = new Scene(root);
Stage stage = new Stage();
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.resizableProperty().setValue(Boolean.FALSE);
Main.getMainStage().close();
Main.setMainStage(stage);
List<Products> productsList = MySQLOperations.getProductsListByCategory("1");
List<ProductCategory> productCategory = MySQLOperations.getProductCategoryList();
System.out.println(productCategory.size());
List<Button> listProductCategory = new ArrayList<>();
HBox listCategoryHBox = new HBox();
for (ProductCategory pc : productCategory) {
    Button productCategoryBtn = new Button();
    productCategoryBtn.setText(pc.getCategoryName());
    // productCategoryBtn.setOnAction(value);
    productCategoryBtn.setId("productCategoryBtn_" + pc.getKeyProductCategory());
    productCategoryBtn.setPrefWidth(88);
    productCategoryBtn.setPrefHeight(32);
    listProductCategory.add(productCategoryBtn);
}
listCategoryHBox.getChildren().addAll(listProductCategory);
CartController fxmlCont = (CartController) myLoader.getController();
fxmlCont.setProducts(listCategoryHBox);
stage.show();
```

I even created some temp HBox, so I can somehow push it in. In `CartController` are controllers for `fxml_cart.fxml`, and in it is

```
@FXML
private HBox products;
```

on witch I call `fxmlCont.setProducts(listCategoryHBox);`

Comment: Just pass the data. Then do all the other stuff in `CartController`.

Comment: You should call methods on the controller to do this. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml for various ways to access the controller after loading the FXML